# Проблема с background-color

Tags: html, css

Есть небольшая проблема с background-color. Хотелось, чтобы этот серый цвет был на всю красную рамку, а не только на текст. Код с картинкой прикрепил. Спасибо за ответ!

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Verdana;
}

.nav_menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #ffb400;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 15px;
    position: relative;
}

.nav_menu li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.nav_menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #7700ff;
    margin-right: 7px;
    font-size: 15px;

}

.nav_menu li a:hover {
    color: red;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<nav>
 <ul class="nav_menu">
  <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Услуги</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

[image: background]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Verdana;
}

.nav_menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #ffb400;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.nav_menu li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.nav_menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #7700ff;
    margin-right: 4px;
    margin-left: 4px;
    font-size: 15px;

}

.nav_menu li:hover {
    color: red;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<nav>
 <ul class="nav_menu">
  <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Услуги</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Цвет текста на красный не меняется (:

Answer (score 1):

1. `padding: 15px;` уберите из `ul`, добавьте его в `li`.
2. Высоту у `li` сделайте `100%`.

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Verdana;
}

.nav_menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #ffb400;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.nav_menu li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    height: 100%;
}

.nav_menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #7700ff;
    margin-right: 7px;
    font-size: 15px;

}
.nav_menu li:hover  a {
    color: red;
}

.nav_menu li:hover {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<nav>
 <ul class="nav_menu">
  <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Услуги</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```